# How to identify the singleton object in JVM?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

Does JVM manage any special attribute for singleton object? How can I identify that in my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There would be just a single instance of that particular class in the heap. But again, it doesn't necessarily means that that class is a singleton. It can be a normal class just instantiated once.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you meant singleton class's object.. I know there is singleton class which will make sure there is only one instance of that class ever created..(even after taking reflection, serialization-deserialization into consideration) I think you cannot consider an object as a singleton object just because you did not find any other object of the same class.